# A circuit fulfilling equation

Tags: amplifier, equation

I am curious about establishing a circuit that satisfies the equation below:
`−Vout =3⋅Vsource + 2000 ⋅ Isource`

I tried to use an operational amplifier but could not provide any output supplying the equation and the values in voltage and current sources. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean: \$ -V_{OUT}=3\cdot V_{SOURCE}+ 2000\cdot I_{SOURCE}\$? If yes then state what the source limit scenarios can be (remembering that an op-amp cannot deal with input currents much more than 10 mA). Also state what power supplies you have available and what accuracy you expect.

Comment: @Esmeralda If you can provide details on the application of this requirement, it would help us provide a better/more accurate answer to your question.

Comment: @Andyaka Hello, yes. There are no limitations since I will not be applying in a real state. One from each current source, voltage source, and op-amp is okay but there won't be a problem if you use more than one. Pxl I was not sure about what details I should add, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simulation of a working 2 op amp design that will provide a function according to the formula you provided.

[image]
[Simulation Here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgB3cFPEXGvij6QBkNgCdBwgdiE04UEGjhsA5lPlVZtMIUViASlJQoZQsMSFUq86tajQEbAJbHTU-vtjxIpP-4DSNiMUBD1sBCE0XgirRVsIexgnAA8QJkJ6Il5yTAgBXRAASQAdAGcACgBlAHsAV3EAYwYASjY0sARybAw9FGx6HuJacD0ANXLq%20qbW9sFyGkWQQiJaGgXR9InK%20oAXFvKSgEdy7HKAKnKxqYbmg7KSgAdy5UgL8qKKsum7tgBDWjaTwIJaeXiddIQsA%20BQwHy4Cx4Gh4PCQDBhXQmRTQnxsbCEXggmQiCiWaT6f7cXg8am2GkgcFIFhIHE%20ByQCx%20VHwTmkDC8OG8wKBcislRcMA8JQYcxS0zWThUpR0lUKrjy5VUDX0sRcOhRFF8fFKQ1idT6wQ2IGRCmSbWGgZ9U3CeASI3hG2hD1xMWKx18G3%20nWKi300O2MSScNUImaxS4V1cWMa2OeMRAA)

Note: you will want a dual rail (+V/GND/-V) power supply for your op amp!

What is happening here is I am converting the current source into a voltage. Using ohms law we can see that V = I*R, so choosing a resistance of 2000 ohms we can get the coefficient of 2000.
I then buffer the voltage generated at the resistor to prevent any loading from the summing configuration of the next op amp circuit.

The last op amp simultaneously sums, amplifies, and inverts the two voltages, `V1 = V(source)` and `V2 = I(source)*2000`. It separately amplifies the two, so I have an amplification of 1 (unity) on the voltage produced by the buffer, and I have an amplification of 3 on the V(source) to provide the 3*V(source) portion of the formula.

The op amp circuit follows the formula `-V(out) = 3*V(source) + 2000*I(source)`

**Check this resource on op amp design** [Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much Pxl for this amazing circuit. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @Esmeralda no problem, I am glad I was helpful.